# Proof explanation - weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, proof-explanation

> Let $(X_i)$ be i.i.d. random variables with mean $\mu$ and finite variance. Then $$\dfrac{X_1 + \dots + X_n}{n} \to \mu \text{ weakly }$$

I have the proof here:

[image]

What I don't understand is, why it suffices to show that $F_{S_n/n}(\mu - \epsilon) \to 0$ and $F_{S_n / n}(\mu + \epsilon) \to 1$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ for every $x$. AFAIK, we must prove that $F_{S_n/n}$ converges to the distribution function for $\mu$ for every continuity point of $F$ - why do we consider the discontinuity point?, i.e. it converges to $1$ for $x \geq \mu$ and to $0$ for $x < \mu$, but I am not sure how this shows that.

Comment: see my answer below, but I think it comes down to there being a typo in the proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a typo in the proof, because it should say "for each $\epsilon >0$", NOT "for each $x>0$", since the limit being taken is as $n \to \infty$, not as $\epsilon \to 0$.

To show convergence in distribution, we only need to show convergence at all of the points of continuity of the limit RV (NOT at any point of discontinuity, i.e. $\mu$).

Hence what the proof is saying is that if we show the limit approaches the right value as $n \to \infty$ for every *other* point besides $\mu$ (which is what that shows, if we change "for $x>0$" to "for all $\epsilon > 0$"), then we have shown the convergence in distribution.

I.e. since every other point besides $\mu$ is of the form $\mu - \epsilon$ or $\mu + \epsilon$ for *some* $\epsilon > 0$.

Since convergence in distribution to *a constant* is equivalent to showing convergence in probability to a constant, we are done.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you